# reactjs: How to load json data locally?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript

I write a script to show json data, currently I load data as runtimeload. 
How to modify code to load it as locally?  Would you help take a look? Thank you! I want to build my script as library and buildin json files, and not allowed others to modify these data.

Error as below:

```
./src/components.js
Module not found: You attempted to import ../data/a.json which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

```
type State = {
  index: number;
};

type Props = {
 Duration: number;
 Size: number;
 serviceData: typeof service;
};

export class DataFile extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  timerID: number;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      testData: this.data(),
    };
    this.timerID=0;
  }

  getData =()=> {
    switch (this.props.serviceData) {
      case service["test_a"] :
        return require('../data/a.json');

      case service["test_b"] :
        return require('../data/b.json');

      case service["test_c"] :
        return require('../data/c.json');

      default:
        return require('../data/c.json');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Import your **json data** folder inside the **Src** directory.

Comment: Thank you. I want to build these json data with my code. Others can use it as library (without data.json list) but I don't want to let them modify data.

Answer (score 0):

You should manipulate a JS Object in your code to generate the JSON and [stringify it as JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/stringify) when you want you want to display it.

Eventually you can use the [LocalStorage feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) available in most browser to store your generated JSObject to stringify.

Hope it Helps